# Sum of vector subspaces generally

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding the sum of two vector subspaces.

Let two subspaces: $G_{1}, T_{1} \subset\mathbb R^n$ be subspaces with bases

$ \left\{ \vec{g_{1}},...,\vec{g_{k}} \right\}$ and $\left\{ \vec{t_{1}},...,\vec{t_{m}} \right\}$, respectively.

The sum of vectors subspaces $G_{1} + T_{1}$ is defined as the vector subspace
$ \left\{ \vec{x} + \vec{y} | \vec{x} \in G_{1}, \vec{y} \in T_{1}\right\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$.

What will be the final result of the sum $G_{1} + T_{1}$?

Is it $ \left\{ \vec{g_{1}} + \vec{t_{1}},..., \vec{g_{k}} + \vec{t_{m}} \right\}$?

Comment: Which part of the given definition $\{x + y : x \in G_1, y \in T_1\}$ do you not understand?

Comment: I'm new to sets and linear algebra. Could you explain me how the final result looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $G+T$ will be generated by $\{g_1,\dots,g_k,t_1,\dots t_m\}$, since $g_i=g_i+0,t_i=0+t_i$, and any sum $x+y$ with $x\in G$ and $y\in T$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors.

Generally $\{g_1,\dots,g_k,t_1,\dots t_m\}$ is not a basis of $G+T$. Consider by example $\{(x,y,0)\}+\{(z,0,0)\}=\{(x,y,0)\}$ (i.e. if $V\subset W$, then $V+ W=W$).

$\{g_1,\dots,g_k,t_1,\dots t_m\}$ is a basis of $G+T$ if and only if $G\cap T=\{0\}$, in which case the sum is called a direct sum, and the notation is $\oplus$.

So if you're looking for a generating set, $\{g_1,\dots,g_k,t_1,\dots t_m\}$ is one. If you're looking for a basis, there is no fixed formula in general. The space generated by $\{g_i+t_j\}$ is a subspace of $G+T$, and in general is not $G+T$, as can be seen by $G=T=\mathbb{R}, g=1$ and $t=-1$.

---

Edit:

> Proposition: $\{(x,y,0)\}+\{(z,0,0)\}=\{(x,y,0)\}$

Proof: Since $(x,y,0)+(0,0,0)=(x,y,0)$, we have the inclusion RHS$\subset$LHS.

To prove the other inclusion, let $x\in$LHS. Then $x=u+v$ with $u\in\{(x,y,0)\}$ and $v\in\{(z,0,0)\}$. Write $u=(x_u,y_u,0)$ and $v=(z_v,0,0)$, then $x=u+v=(x_u+z_v,y_u,0)$, then $x\in$RHS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you still explain how {(,,0)}+{(,0,0)}={(,,0)}?

Comment: Done! By the way these are shorten notations. You should write $x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$ inside the brackets.

Comment: Do you mean $v = (z_v, 0, 0)$ in the last line?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. Thanks..